# delayed_job to sidekiq: Reset password email not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, delayed-job, sidekiq

After migrating from `delayed_job` to `sidekiq`, user is now not able to receive `devise` password reset emails. However all the emails passing via custom `ActionMailer` works perfactly.

I verified all the queues but not enqueued.

With `delayed_job` I used `handle_asynchronously` to make it work

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :invitable, :async, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable
  handle_asynchronously :send_reset_password_instructions
end
```

I see 2 queues in `sidekiq` web 1) `default` 2) `mailers`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved.

Need to add following method in `User` model as per [README](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#activejob-integration) for Rails 4.2

```
def send_devise_notification(notification, *args)
  devise_mailer.send(notification, self, *args).deliver_later
end
```